# creating dynamic triangle size on the right side of rectangular using css

Tags: css

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

However im confuse how to create the triangle shaped but in dynamic size as the right side area is a paragraph that could have alot or small content.

I just can't get the structure worked out at the moment

Comment: Post up the code you have so far so we can help out.

Comment: I dont have any idea yet, i can make the outer div to hold the grey color, and create inner div to add dashed border, adding padding to outer div to make the dashed border going inside. but i dont have any idea how to create structure for the triangle style

Comment: I'd check out using `skew()` here. Give this a quick read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/skew

Comment: is that mean the text also skewed? ill give it a try first

Comment: Actually let me make you a little demo once. I think you could do that with a css triangle.

Comment: the you you gave is not working on dynamic height. any idea?

Comment: The hard part with the being dynamic is being able to grow that css triangle as the content grows or shrinks. The only solution there I could think up would be to use some jquery to calculate the height. I'll try a few things out.

Comment: Ok so here's my full attempt, but unfortunately it uses jquery to calculate sizes, so the good part is it can be dynamic. http://jsfiddle.net/e3jdqkv8/4/. The spacing could use some touch ups on the pixels but that's cake. Also this ditched floats for flex-box.

Comment: jquery is okay, the hack is pretty great, thanks @justDan, you just made my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want a triangle shape there, then you can definitely use CSS to make a triangle for that section. Here's a quick demo that float's two div's and uses a CSS triangle.

Triangle CSS:

```
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-top: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
border-left: 10px solid #fff;
```

All together:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.wrap {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 500px;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  background: #4c4c4c;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0 40px;
  width: 70%;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  border-style: dashed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 96%;
  height: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.arrow-left {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
  border-top: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='inner'>
    <div class='left'>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum <br>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
      <div class='arrow-left'></div>      
    </div>
    <div class='right'><p>Lorem Ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</p></div>
    <div class='border'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ogzcLhy/2/

Note: this layout uses floats which can ditched to use `flex-box` which has all kinds of great features to utilize to make cleaner layouts.

Comment: its look great @justDan! but it cant handle dynamic height, right? i need the content to be dynamic , can be alot of text there